# Creating an API in Go to work with Github

Tags: beginner, go

I am fairly new to Golang and I was creating an API to fetch commits from any Github repository using their API. I was then creating a frequency count, based on the date and then sending it to the frontend.

Added a Gist for a better view:
https://gist.github.com/karansinghgit/256a3f69698004cab4024c39767a0be1

Currently, I only work in one main.go and I am not very aware of the programming pracices in Golang. I am using the Mux router to work with http.

I have 2 routes.
The '/' route is handled by `getHome` and '/updateRepository' is handled by `updateRepository` handler.

I maintain a `currentRepository` variable globally.
In both handler methods, I first get the timestamps of all the commits for that repository using Github's API using `getCommitTimeStamps`.

Then I parse the timestamps using `parseTimeStamps`, which first converts the RFC3339 date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` format and then basically create a map to store the frequency for each date.

The only extra method which `updateRepository` handler uses, is `parseURL` which basically extracts the Github Owner Name and Repository name from any Github URL. 
I plan to update this using an input text element on my Frontend.

`init` initialises a new Client for enabling access to Github's API.

I have split everything into functions, what else can I do? What are the things I can clean?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/go-github/v31/github"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

var client *github.Client
var ctx context.Context

type Repository struct {
    Owner string `json:"owner"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
}

type Frequency struct {
    Date  string `json:"date"`
    Count int    `json:"count"`
}

var currentRepository = Repository{
    Owner: "karansinghgit",
    Name:  "foobar",
}

const GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN string = "MY_AUTH_TOKEN"

func init() {
    ctx = context.Background()
    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(
        &oauth2.Token{AccessToken: GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN},
    )
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)
    client = github.NewClient(tc)
}

func parseURL(repoURL *string) Repository {
    res := currentRepository
    if *repoURL != "" {
        index := strings.Index(*repoURL, "github.com")

        repo := *repoURL
        repo = repo[index+11:]
        var base []string
        base = strings.Split(repo, "/")
        var ans []string
        for _, e := range base {
            if e != "" {
                ans = append(ans, e)
            }
        }
        res = Repository{
            Owner: ans[0],
            Name:  ans[1],
        }
    }

    return res
}

func getCommitTimeStamps(repo Repository) []time.Time {
    var commitTimeStamps []time.Time

    opt := &github.CommitsListOptions{
        ListOptions: github.ListOptions{PerPage: 50},
    }

    var allRepositoryCommits []*github.RepositoryCommit
    for {
        repositoryCommits, resp, err := client.Repositories.ListCommits(ctx, repo.Owner, repo.Name, opt)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        allRepositoryCommits = append(allRepositoryCommits, repositoryCommits...)
        if resp.NextPage == 0 {
            break
        }
        opt.Page = resp.NextPage
    }

    for _, e := range allRepositoryCommits {
        commitTimeStamps = append(commitTimeStamps, *e.GetCommit().Author.Date)
    }
    return commitTimeStamps
}

func parseTimeStamps(commitTimeStamps []time.Time) []Frequency {
    const RFC3339FullDate = "2006-08-06"
    timeSeries := make([]string, len(commitTimeStamps))
    for i, t := range commitTimeStamps {
        timeSeries[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", t.Year(), t.Month(), t.Day())
    }
    m := make(map[string]int)
    for _, t := range timeSeries {
        m[t]++
    }
    var f []Frequency

    for k, v := range m {
        f = append(f, Frequency{
            Date:  k,
            Count: v,
        })
    }
    return f
}

func getHome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    commitTimeStamps := getCommitTimeStamps(currentRepository)
    commitTimeObjects := parseTimeStamps(commitTimeStamps)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(commitTimeObjects)
}

func updateRepository(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var url struct {
        URL string `json:"url"`
    }

    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&url)
    currentRepository = parseURL(&url.URL)
    fmt.Println(currentRepository)
    // currentRepository looks like {bradtraversy reactcharts}
    commitTimeStamps := getCommitTimeStamps(currentRepository)
    commitTimeObjects := parseTimeStamps(commitTimeStamps)
    // commitTimeObjects looks like [{2016-04-21 2} {2016-04-23 5} {2016-04-25 1}]
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    fmt.Println(currentRepository)
    _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(commitTimeObjects)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.Use(mux.CORSMethodMiddleware(router))
    router.HandleFunc("/", getHome).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")
    router.HandleFunc("/updateRepository", updateRepository).Methods("PUT", "OPTIONS")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why I was downvoted. I posted this in compliance with the rules of the community. Please add a comment to help me improve as to why this was downvoted.

Comment: @KaranSingh Also edit your question body and add a detailed description what your code is supposed to do please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ updated with the required explanation